# Decode a search string in the url

Tags: php, jquery

I have a search text input. When i submit the searching, the text will get into the $_GET, and i will land on a search.php site.

```
    function search_k()
    {
    return""!=$.trim($("#country_id").val())&&
    (document.location="/kereses?k="+$("#country_id").val())
}
```

If i type in this: some test text
The url will be like this: kereses?k=some%20test%20text

How can i replace the %20 with a + mark? My problem is, that when i search for a product, that name has a + mark, i didnt get any result.

If i echo $_GET['k'] with php, that replaces the + mark to empty whitespaces. I have a real_escape_string function on the $_GET['k'].

**UPDATE:**

It still dont work, no changes. I always get the %20 in the GET. If i alert the word var, i get the right text.

```
function search_k()
{
    if($.trim($('#country_id').val()) != "" )
    {
        var word = encodeURIComponent($('#country_id').val());
        document.location = '/kereses?k='+word;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need encodeURIComponent(); javascript function

```
 var x= $("#country_id").val(); //get field value
 x = encodeURIComponent(x);  // encode it before passing
 (document.location="/kereses?k="+x); // pass your field value
```

that's it

Comment: It dont works, the problem is the same.
document.location="/kereses?k="+encodeURL($("#country_id").val()))

Comment: I have edited my answer as encodeURIComponent is right function because encodeURI() function encodes special characters, except: , / ? : @ & = + $ # got this from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURI.asp)